# Single variable true or false statements

Tags: notation, boolean-algebra

If I have a true or false statement S, depending on a varible x, is there some standard function or opperation in formal logic, that takes the statement S and the variable x, and outputs $1$ if statement S is true for x, and $0$ if the statement S is false for x.

Answer (score 2):

One name for this is the [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket):

> In mathematics, the *Iverson bracket*, named after Kenneth E. Iverson, is a notation that denotes a number that is $1$ if the condition in square brackets is satisfied, and $0$ otherwise. More exactly,
>   $$[P] =
> \begin{cases}
> 1 & \text{if $P$ is true;} \\
> 0 & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   where $P$ is a statement that can be true or false.